# Spherical polar surface plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I have to plot antenna response pattern in a spherical polar plot.
I first create the theta(`t`) and phi(`p`) values. Then there is F_c and F_s that has to calculated for each `theta[i]` and `phi[i]`.

```
t=np.linspace(-math.pi/2, math.pi/2, num=x)
p=np.linspace(-math.pi, math.pi, num=x)

for k in xrange(x):
    for j in xrange(x):
            for i in xrange(n):
                    F_c=F_c_F_s.F_c(theta[i],phi[i],t[j],p[k])
                    F_s=F_c_F_s.F_s(theta[i],phi[i],t[j],p[k])
                    sum_F_c[j][k]=sum_F_c[j][k]+F_c
                    sum_F_s[j][k]=sum_F_s[j][k]+F_s
                    mod_F[j][k]=math.log((math.pow(sum_F_c[j][k],2)+math.pow(sum_F_s[j][k],2)),10)
```

Now we have a value of `mod_F` for each `t` and `p`.  For each value of theta and correspondingly for each value of phi I calculate Cartesian coordinates. Then to make the surface plot I have the following:

```
fig = p.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_wireframe(x,y,z)
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=1,cstride=1,cmap=cm.jet)
p.show()
```

The problem is, it is incredibly slow! Even for `x=10` i.e. a 10 x 10 grid, it take a lot of time. Is there a way to do this in better and faster manner?

Comment: what are `F_c` and `F_s`. It might be possible to vectorize that triple loop.

Comment: `F_c` and `F_s` are two components of the pattern. I have to calculate both for all `i` and sum them. Finally I need the `log` of sum of squares of (these summed over i) `F_c` and `F_s`. The slower part of the code is the plotting part.

Comment: The time is almost certainly being spend in F_c_F_s.F_c and F_c_F_s.F_s; nothing else in the loop takes all that much time (at least, when only performing it 1000 times). Without seeing the code for those, there's not much we can do.

Comment: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/voqes4s6owbd1q5/AADFEl8dg1G8wD5nT-SnJB76a?dl=0) is the link for the codes. F_map.py is the main code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code

Comment: The issue is I am over-calculating some quantity which makes the plotting surface very slow. Can anyone please help me find where is the issue?

Comment: Where does `n`, `theta` and `phi` come from?

Comment: `n`, `theta` and `phi` are user specified. Currently I am using `n=3`. It will go to 50 at max. For `n=3`, we have 3 `theta` and `phi` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
t=np.linspace(0, np.pi, num=x)
p=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,num=x)
[T,P]=np.meshgrid(t,p)
F_c=0.0
F_s=0.0

for i in xrange(n):
    F_c+=F_c_F_s.F_c(theta[i],phi[i],T,P)
    F_s+=F_c_F_s.F_s(theta[i],phi[i],T,P)
mod_F=(np.log10((np.power(F_c,2)+np.power(F_s,2))))
```